# Why we put '-' sign with linux commands flags?

Tags: linux, command

In Linux,If we want to run any command with flags then we are used to put '-' sign with them. 
for example:
tar -xzvf ....
tar -czvf ..
rm -rf ...
Can anyone tell me what is the significance of that?

Answer (score 2):

Actually tar is so old... you can also not use `-` (it's one of the **rare** commands that treat options by their placement only, and doesn't always need the `-` in front)

But it's a (good) convention, used to easily find out what is an option (to change the behaviour of the command) and what is an "argument" (to be processed by the command)

Usually programms will be launched with :

```
program -option -option2 arg1  arg2 arg3 -arg4
```

and will process arguments `arg1`, `arg2`, `arg3` and `-arg4` as arguments with the program (following also the change induced by the option and option2) (note that the "process things as options" stops as soon as it encounters an entry not starting with `-`, so that `-arg4` is also treated as an argument, not an option!)

But in real life, it's not always easy to know what is an option : if you want to delete a file named `-something`, and try

```
rm -something
```

rm will complain that it can't recognize some options (which ones depends on your implementatino of `rm` !), and also could complain that there is no argument (ie, no filename to delete)

In that case you'll need to :

```
rm ./-something
```

so that the argument doesn't start with `-` anymore (it now starts with `./-`)

(you can also, for SOME commands, use `--` to separate options from the rest : once THOSE (and only those) programms encounter `--` they consider the rest as arguments and not options. So you could also do : `rm -- -something` ... but it is less portable!)

Note:

- older programs use only 1 character options ( ex: `rm -v -i something` ) and some not-so-old programs allow you to "concatenate" them into one (ex: `rm -vi something`) ...
- newer programms usually also support "longer options", usually using `--` instead of `-` to differentiate a "long name option" from a "concatenation of several small options" : exemple:  `rm --help`

Answer (score 0):

Indicates an argument to the program. e.g.

```
tar -x -z -v -f /dir/file
```

, where /dir/file is a value to the -f switch, so no "-" for it.

Some programs allow options to be combined like

```
tar -xzvf /dir/file
```

Some programs (like tar) allow you to omit it like:

```
tar xzvf /dir/file
```